# Accessing and performing operations on queryset data in Django

Tags: python, django

If I get a queryset object like below

```
review_object = Review.objects.filter(property_id=prop.values('id')).annotate(total=Sum('star_rating'))
```

how do I access this object to perform further operations? To expand, I need to be able to sum the 'star_rating' field per property_id. I've tried this:

```
count_stars = 0
    for ro in review_object:
        count_stars += ro.star_rating
```

But this displays all stars for all properties.

I've tried the aggregate function but this returns a dictionary object which does not meet my needs when rendering in the template. I can provide more info if required.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get sums of rating per property id using django ORM, you need to specify `values()`:

```
review_object = Review.objects.values('property_id').annotate(total=Sum('star_rating'))
```

Another option is to sum up rating per property "in python" using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

review_object = Review.objects.all()
results = defaultdict(int)
for ro in review_object:
    results[ro.property_id] += ro.star_rating
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @CiaranReen I've updated the answer, included an option using django ORM.